# How to know which library uses a given symbol?

Tags: ocaml

Js_of_ocaml tells me my bytecode uses `caml_blit_string_to_bigstring` somewhere. Is there a way to find which library introduces this dependency?

Comment: Pretty sure that's one of janestreet's libraries. They don't (yet) work with jsoo.

Comment: @Drup I'm only using cow, lwt and cohttp.

Comment: It's sexplib, which is used pervasively inside cohttp/mirage.

Comment: Sexplib seems to work fine with js_of_ocaml. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to spot `caml_blit_string_to_bigstring` into cstruct.cma, using ocamlobjinfo.

Using `opam list --depends-on=...`, I found that Hex uses Cstruct, Ezjsonm uses Hex and Cow uses Ezjsonm.

Now I don't know for sure if it's the code of Ezjsonm that I'm using that triggers the crash.

**EDIT**
I've pinned a custom version of Hex that doesn't rely on cstruct. The problem is gone now.

Comment: nice usage of opam list --depends-on.

Comment: And opam-pin is so powerful! It tooks me only a couple of minutes to validate my hypothesis.

Comment: It's really useful during development too

Answer (score 1):

You could try something this:

```
cd $(opam config var lib)
ocamlobjinfo */*.cmo */*.cmx */*.cma */.cmxa | less
```

And then search for your symbol, once you find it move up to find out the `File` line in which the symbol occurs.

This could also be in sub-sub+ folders but I'm a terrible shell script programmer so I'll let you figure out the right invocation.